# Corroborating a differnce in differences identification strategy

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, model-evaluation, estimators, difference-in-difference

I read in Mostly harmless econometrics that a good way of testing whether a difference in differences is a good identification strategy is running this equation:

[image]

where the first sums are post-treatment effects (interactions of the treatment dummy with dummies for years after the program) and the other sum represents anticipatory effects (interactions of the treatment dummy with dummies for years before the program) but also interacted with the control variables. The bok says that if the identification strategy is correct we should get that anticipatory effects are not significant, id est, betas of the second sigma are not significant. Could you explain me why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of corrections:

- This is not too important here, but you don't seem to have the formula quite right from the book.  In the book (p. 237), there is a $+$ sign between the second sum and the vector of control variables.
- Also, the two sums are not interaction terms.  The first sum is a sum of treatment dummies for $m$ periods *before* (and including) the period in which a policy was implemented, multiplied by their regression coefficients.  The second sum is a sum of treatment dummies for $q$ periods *after* the period in which a policy was implemented, also multiplied by their regression coefficients.

The point of estimating this type of equation (the first sum can also be omitted for this to work) is to perform a Granger causality test and see if there is a significant association between future treatment exposures and outcome in the current period.  If those dummies for future periods were found to be significant, it would violate the Granger test because future should not predict current outcomes.  It would indicate that a significant finding from a DiD model without those additional dummy terms was potentially due to changes in trends that occurred before implementation of the policy.

The reason why that second sum is referred to as "anticipatory effects", even though it includes dummies for *future* treatment exposures, is that those terms can be interpreted as the effects on current outcome of individuals' expectations about whether treatment will continue to be in effect in future periods.  In other words, this model is designed to examine the possibility that future treatment exposures are anticipated by current outcomes.

Here are some references for further reading:

- https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-publhealth-040617-013507
- https://www.jasondebacker.com/classes/Lecture5_Notes_DD_DDD.pdf
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5848493/ (example of this type of test implemented in actual research)
- http://faculty.smu.edu/Millimet/classes/eco7377/papers/malani%20reif%202015.pdf (paper on measuring anticipation effects)